# Case statements returns same vavlues

Tags: sql-server

I have the following case statement given to me.

```
   SELECT schoolc,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN (ident) ELSE 0 END)AS       [total Students],
   COUNT(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN('A','P') AND subtestc IN('ela','Math')  AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN (ident) ELSE 0 END)AS [students above]

  FROM [dbo].[qw_star_testing_detail]
  WHERE subtestc IN('ela','Math')
  AND tscrtypc ='A'
  GROUP BY schoolc
```

it is trying to do two separate calculations total students and student above but it is turning the same value for both. when I run this i get 1966 which is correct but when I apply it to my case i get 2362 . I has to be something simple.

```
  select COUNT(ident),schoolc
  FROM [dbo].[qw_star_testing_detail]
  WHERE subtestc IN('ela','Math')
  AND tscrtypc ='A'
  AND testscore IN('A','P')
  GROUP BY schoolc
  ORDER BY schoolc
```

Answer (score 0):

COUNT([column]) returns the number of rows in the result set that have a non-null value in the specified column.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT schoolc,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [total Students],
    SUM(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN ('A','P') AND subtestc IN ('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [students above]
FROM [dbo].[qw_star_testing_detail]
WHERE subtestc IN('ela','Math')
AND tscrtypc ='A'
GROUP BY schoolc
```

Comment: Great thank now to add to that I would  like to get a percent from the above two.  tried the following

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `ELSE 0` portion of your `CASE` Statements, then the records not matching the `CASE` criteria will return `NULL` which is excluded in aggregate functions.

```
  SELECT  schoolc
         ,COUNT(CASE WHEN (subtestc) IN('ela','Math') AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN (ident) END)AS       [total Students]
         ,COUNT(CASE WHEN (testscore)IN('A','P') AND subtestc IN('ela','Math')  AND tscrtypc ='A'THEN (ident) END)AS [students above]
  FROM [dbo].[qw_star_testing_detail]
  WHERE subtestc IN('ela','Math')
    AND tscrtypc ='A'
  GROUP BY schoolc
```